# How do I calculate this logarithmic complexity using summations?

Tags: for-loop, big-o, computer-science

**My Question**

What is the Big-O complexity for this code snippet?
Consider n as a power of 4.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i = i*4)                      
    for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)                 
       // constant statement
```

**What I know so far**

I tried making this code into a summation to find the complexity.
This is what I got:
[image]

I got (base 4) log(n) by computing the series 4, 4^2, 4^3 ... 4^r = n.
r = (base 4) log(n).

I'm now stuck at this summation:

[image]

Please let me know If I'm doing something wrong or there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re on the right track here, but your innermost summation is wrong. You are right that the outer loop will iterate log_4 n times, but you’ve set up the outer sum so that i counts up as 1, 2, 3, ..., log_4 n, rather than 4^0, 4^1, 4^2, ... 4^log_4 n. As a result, that inner summation’s upper bound is incorrect. The bound should be 4^i, not i.

If you set things up this way, you’ll find that the overall sum is

> 4^0 + 4^1 + 4^2 + ... + 4^log_4 n
>
> = (4^(log_4 n + 1) - 1) / (4 - 1) (using the formula for the sum of a geometric series
>
> = (4(4^log_4 n) - 1) / 3
>
> = (4n - 1) / 3
>
> = Θ(n).

Answer (score 0):

You may use wolframalpha to get the result for extreme accuracy.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i,+i%3D1+to+log_4(n)